# Unable to access service reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wsdl, asmx, service-reference

I have successfully added a service reference to my Visual Studio 2013 project.

I cannot however reference it in code.

For example, given the project name "myproject", and the service reference name "thirdpartyasmx", I cannot use this using directive...

```
using myproject.thirdpartyasmx
```

I cannot instantiate the class directly either...

```
thirdpartyasmx test = new thirdpartyasmx();
```

I have tried building the solution before trying to reference the service reference.

This is not something I do regularly, so I'm afraid I'm missing a step.

Comment: Is it because the service reference starts with a numerical...

Comment: corrected in example code...

Comment: So... Is the compiler giving you errors or are you getting runtime erros

Comment: Try disabling `reuse types from referenced assemblies`.

Comment: Are you adding it strictly via Add Service Reference, or are you clicking on the Advanced Button in the Add Service reference dialog box, clicking the "Advanced" button and then clicking on Add Web Reference?  This is for adding legacy (ASMX) web services.

Comment: @Silvermind - that is what I needed. Would you create an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: @Tim - you were also correct - if you leave your comment as an answer, I can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATED based on OP feedback**

When you click on Add Service Reference, click on the Advanced button in the bottom left of the dialog box:

[image]

Clear the Reuse types in referenced assemblies checkbox (by default it's checked).

[image]

Comment: -1 why would you recommend the OP use a web reference? What was said in the question that made you think this was a good idea?

Comment: @Tim - the image above should have "Reuse types in referenced assemblies" circled, not "Add Web Reference..." Still, +1 and thanks for the help.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - OP appears to be using an ASMX service, and I've seen in the past where people have had better luck with Add Web Reference for ASMX vs Add Service Reference.  Why would you recommend against it (other than it being 2.0 framework)?  I almost never use service reference myself (unless I'm doing a quick prototype) - for fully developed applications I use `ChannelFactory<T>`.

Comment: @EthanPelton - Sorry, I thought you meant add the web reference.  I've updated the answer and the screenshot based on your feedback.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: @Tim: that's in addition to the fact that even a service reference is so much less capable than a web reference. Simple example: compare how you turn on tracing in a web reference vs. how you do it in a service reference.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - I know that ASMX is legacy.  It seemed to me that OP was accessing a legacy technology and my comment was specific to adding a web service reference, which OP asked me to post as an answer.  In any event, I've corrected the answer to match what worked for OP so future readers will not be misled.

Comment: @tim: I was replying to your question about why I would recommend against web references.

Comment: @Tim:+1 Worked for me in case of WCF also. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the using directive at the top of the class, you can just instantiate the service reference inside the class using the name you gave to the service when referencing it:

```
 public class MyClassName
 {
     protected void SomeMethod()
     {
         thirdpartyasmx.ThirdpartyasmxServiceClient service = new thirdpartyasmx.ThirdpartyasmxServiceClient();
     }
 }
```